# Calculator script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a script which calculates the valuta.

I have no clue how to say this in English but how can I create a simple script which calculates the number:

if number is 15
echo 1

if number is 30
echo 2

if number is 45
echo 3

So if I type in the input 15, the number 1 will appear. If I type in the number 30, the number 2 will appear

Comment: Are those the only 3 numbers? Or do you want to keep it going? EG: Number 60 = 4?

Comment: Are you trying to divide any given number by 15?

Comment: @CarlMarkham yes, exactly that! I think you know what i am trying to say

Comment: What if you type something that isn't divisible by 15, like 10 or 20?

Comment: @Juhana it should be left blank

Comment: @tourniquet_grab so simple possible, javascript or jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do that :

First the javascript :

```
<script>
function calculate() {
    var number = document.getElementById('number').value;

    //This if() is here to make sure that number is an int

    if(number / 15 === parseInt(number / 15, 10)){

        var result = document.getElementById('result');

        //Then you print out the result
        result.innerHTML = number / 15;
    }
}
</script>
```

And here is your HTML :

```
Number : <input type="text" id="number" onkeyup='calculate()'/><br>
Result : <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! that's freakin awesome. have a good halloween my sir

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you'll have to make a form with an input field in HTML. Attach a callback to the submit button. So when the user submits the form, the callback gets executed. Fetch the input, divide it by 15 and show the result in HTML.